# Bug with Spring Cloud Dataflow Container Task Deployment?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

***Version*** : `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn-1.2.2.RELEASE` 
***Issue***   : All OOTB / Custom Task Apps seem to be ***NOT*** working with Yarn Deployer (I Specifically tested with `timestamp-task-1.3.0.RELEASE` and a hello world Custom Task built per the reference doc).

We have a Yarn cluster where all the streams that we have deployed are running fine which rules out any issue with hadoop/yarn cluster. The moment we try to deploy a task, the task exits with code 0 with below message logged in Yarn Container/AppMaster stdout

```
2018-09-19 18:04:20.782 DEBUG 22625 --- [ask-scheduler-2] o.s.yarn.am.allocate.AbstractAllocator   : completed container: container_1536919363436_0805_01_000002 with status=ContainerStatus: [ContainerId: container_1536919363436_0805_01_000002, State: COMPLETE, Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1536919363436_0805_01_000002
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
, ExitStatus: 1, ]
```

***Full AppMaster Log can be found [here](https://anotepad.com/note/read/tm6mgg) and corresponding servers.yml can be found [here](https://anotepad.com/notes/89fa2w)*** 

**Any help is Appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question -- our yarn server had log aggregation enabled and hence container logs weren't displayed immediately and I had to grep through the aggregated logs to find out why custom tasks weren't launching. Once we (temporarily) disabled log aggregation in yarn, custom task's Container.stdout and Container.stderror were visible under log directory configured in yarn-site.xml